# Why can't I refresh any of my sandboxes

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, full-sandbox

I am unable to refresh any of my sandboxes
We have 20 remaining Developer sandboxes
We have used 5 Developer, 1 Partial and 1 FullCopy.

Answer (score 4):

It was because we recently had removed our license for the FullCopy sandbox... meaning:

Even though the FullCopy was locked we were still using 1 Full Copy more than were were provisioned.

And hence Salesforce prevents refresh on all sandboxes until we are within sandbox limits.

**Solution:
I deleted the FullCopy and the refresh buttons returned.**

***NB:** if you delete it, it is gone gone.*

It was not related to the "Manage Sandbox" permission I already had that set as system admin.

Comment: *if you delete it, it is gone gone.* Well, sort of. The deletion is queued for a few days before the hard delete. It can be restored by way if a support ticket if you make a mistake. Not that I'd recommend depending on this, but salesforce.com does try to prevent oppsies from being too obnoxious.

Comment: Good to know, thank you !

Comment: Late last night (tired) I went off looking for sandbox permissions. I already had "Manage Sandboxes" of course. woke up in the morning and had the ahha moment :)